# rails server を起動すると image not found エラーが出る

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

ローカルで `bundle exec rails s` を行うと、下記のエラーが出ました。

```
/Users/xxxxxx/project_name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.11.1/lib/ffi/library.rb:145:in `block in ffi_lib': 

Could not open library '/Users/xxxxxx/project_name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sassc-2.2.1/ext/libsass.bundle': 

dlopen(/Users/xxxxxx/project_name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sassc-2.2.1/ext/libsass.bundle, 5): image not found (LoadError)
```

エラーの通り`/Users/xxxxxx/project_name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sassc-2.2.1/ext/` を見に行ってみると、確かに `libsass.bundle` はありませんでした。(libsassというものはある)

また、作業プロジェクト内で `vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sassc-2.2.1/ext/` を見に行っても libsass.bundle はなく、libsass のみ存在するという状況です。

調べてもこれといった解決策が見当たりませんでしたので、解決方法または解決手順の知見ある方がいらっしゃればご助言いただきたいです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

**環境**

- Mac OS Catalina
- ruby 2.6.4
- gem は `bundle install --path vendor/bundle` でインストール

**初めて発生した状況**
mysql を uninstall した後 brew install で再インストールしたタイミングで出ました

**試したこと**
rbenv 経由で ruby(2.6.4)の再インストール

Answer (score 0):

一応下記の2つの方法を試したところ、どちらでも rails server は起動するようになりました。

- bundle update => Gemfile.lock が更新される => bundle exec rails s
- Gemfile.lock を消す => bundle install --path vendor/bundle => bundle exec rails s

Gemfile.lock で参照されるライブラリに原因がありそうということはわかりましたが、根本的な原因解明にはなっていません。

むしろ gem を更新していないのに Gemfile.lock が変更差分として出てしまうのもよくないポイントだと思います。

ですので、引き続き回答はオープンにさせていただきます。